# what is wrong with this code in php?

Tags: php, html, http

I write a link like that inside of

```
('http://torrentz.eu/search?f='.the_title());
```

but .thetitle() part not working.My website see that like text.
Can someone help me ?

My Full Code Is :

```
<div id="proluk" style="height:300px;width:500px;background:#ff0;overflow:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;">
            <?
            $sayfa = file_get_contents('http://torrentz.eu/search?f='.the_title());
            preg_match_all('~<a href="(.*?)">(.*)</a>~', $sayfa, $cikti);

            foreach ($cikti[1] as $link) {
                echo '<a href="http://torrentz.eu'.$link .'"  > Torrent İndir <br />';
            }  
            ?>
</div>
```

EDIT:
it is a worpress blog so the_title() get me title of the page
i have a game website,i try to pull same games in torrentz.eu,but i my file_get_contents got syntax problems (i guess)
it is works :

```
sayfa = file_get_contents('http://torrentz.eu/search?f=somegamename');
```

but it is not work:

```
sayfa = file_get_contents('http://torrentz.eu/search?f='.the_title());
```

my website is : http://www.oyundetay.org
you can see the example inside of the post (yellow area)

Comment: Can you provide more context? Where are you including this code? Are you using a CMS like Wordpress?

Comment: What is the rest of the code? What does the function `the_title()` do?

Comment: @brbcoding you are wrong it is running.

Comment: I don't see the `the_title()` function defined anywhere.

Comment: It is a Wordpress Blog, so the_title() get me title of the page.

Comment: @ÇelikGümüşdağ then you need to provide more information. You haven't given any context or anything of value to us. Good luck figuring it out if you can't even tell us what the problem is.

Comment: Are you sure you have short tags enabled? Even if you do, you should use the full `<?php`

Comment: **Things which which you should ask yourself:** - Can you run PHP on your server? - Is the_title() a function and is it declared? - Isn't it thetitle() or something similar? - Have you included the PHP tags?

Comment: @ÇelikGümüşdağ: see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18360180/1438393) below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file_get_contents('http://torrentz.eu/search?f='.the_title());
```

`the_title()` will echo out the title of the post when it's called like that. So there's nothing to be concatenated to the end of the string. The simplest way is to call `get_the_title()`, which returns the same string, instead of echoing it:

```
file_get_contents('http://torrentz.eu/search?f='.get_the_title());
```

**Edit**

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($cikti[1] as $link) {
    $i++;
    if ($i > 5) {
            echo '<a href="http://torrentz.eu'.$link .'"  > Torrent İndir <br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: @ÇelikGümüşdağ - which array? If you just want to skip past the first few elements in your foreach loop, you can add a counter, and not print anything if the counter is less than six.

Comment: Otherwise, I'd suggest adding a separate question, as I don't really follow what you're asking for.

Comment: first 5 items are irrelevant with what I looking for,can I delete them  ?

Comment: @ÇelikGümüşdağ - I've edited my answer with a very basic way of doing this - it'll skip over the first 5 entries.

Answer (score 2):

As the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) says:

> **`the_title`** Displays or returns the title of the current post. This tag may only be used within The Loop, to get the title of a post outside of the loop use `get_the_title`.

So, simply change

```
file_get_contents('http://torrentz.eu/search?f='.the_title());
```

to

```
file_get_contents('http://torrentz.eu/search?f='. get_the_title());
```

and that should fix the issue (hopefully).

Refer to the documentation for more information: [**`get_the_title()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title)

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a config setting that can prevent `file()` and related functions from accessing remote data, such as from a `http://` address.

See here for more info: [PHP allow-url-fopen ini flag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)

Most likely, your server has this config switched on.

If this is the case, you have two options:

1. Switch the config setting off.
2. Rewrite your code to use CUrl instead of `file_get_contents()`.

If you're running the site on a shared hosting server, option (1) is unlikely to be possible, so you'll probably need to do option (2).